# array_diff issue - PHP

Tags: php

I have `array1` :

```
    array(20) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "0x0000000000000013620010713E5A" } 
    [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "0x000000000000001077002942CE57" } 
    [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "0x20120427850602000103026906B2" } 
    [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "0xE20062969619018824701915D683" } 
    [4]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(30) "0x0000000008002216572D06103CF6" } [5]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(30) "0xE2004465650F015224401B255262" } [6]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(30) "0xE20092012053100000002850D14E" } 
    [7]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "0x300833B2DDD901400000000039BB" } 
    [8]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "0xE2002996961802570960B3F06912" } 
    [9]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "0x000000000000000000501420B8B6" } 
    [10]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(30) "0x201203298478040001020252A5EC" } [11]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(30) "0xE20010008007026819204FCAF906" } [12]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(30) "0x0000000000000000000007485DF6" } [13]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(30) "0xE2001036990F008812908EA5481C" } [14]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(30) "0x0019000000000000000043B94C3A" } [15]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(30) "0x0000000000000000004004490529" } [16]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(30) "0x0000000000000000000010066E18" } [17]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(30) "Error 0100:   syntax error at ''" } [18]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(34) "Error 0102:   Error performing query" } [19]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> NULL } }
```

In `array2`:

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "0x0019000000000000000043B94C3A" } 
[1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "0x0000000000000000004004490529" } [2]=> array(1) { 
[0]=> string(30) "0x0000000000000000000010066E18" } 
[3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "0xE2004465650F015224401B255262" } } array(0) { }
```

Now with both of these I am using an `array_diff()` to check if `array2` does not have any `series` listed within `array1`

`array_diff()`:

```
$results = array_diff($devices_ForUser, $device_CurrentIDS);
```

My issue is when checking if `$results` is empty, it is empty when it should not be.

Suggestions and thoughts?

David

Comment: $devices_ForUser, $device_CurrentIDS - which of those is the first?

Comment: Check my question it is at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php :

> This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array. Of
>   course you can check deeper dimensions by using array_diff($array1[0],
>   $array2[0]);.

You have a nested array, this cant work.

**EDIT:**

This may work:

```
function array_values_recursive($ary)
{
   $lst = array();
   foreach( array_keys($ary) as $k ){
      $v = $ary[$k];
      if (is_scalar($v)) {
         $lst[] = $v;
      } elseif (is_array($v)) {
         $lst = array_merge( $lst,
            array_values_recursive($v)
         );
      }
   }
   return $lst;
}

$result = array_diff(array_values_recursive($devices_ForUser), array_values_recursive($device_CurrentIDS));
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Oh I see, so I just have to iterate through?

Comment: no, this will be not enough.. you will have to get all the values in one level of an array, (for both arrays) then you can use the array_diff.

Comment: Could you supply me with an example?

Comment: Awesome this worked perfect, who ever thought using recursive could be useful!

Comment: actually the results seems to be storing correctly but there is a gap between 3 and 5 within the array index, why is that?

Comment: can you pastebin.com the contents of the arrays and mark the gap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SPL to do what you want.

```
$array_1=array( 
0=> array( 0=>  "0x0000000000000013620010713E5A" ),
1=> array( 0=>  "0x000000000000001077002942CE57" ),
2=> array( 0=>  "0x20120427850602000103026906B2" ) ,
3=> array( 0=>  "0xE20062969619018824701915D683" ),
4=> array( 0=>  "0x0000000008002216572D06103CF6" ) ,
5=> array( 0=>  "0xE2004465650F015224401B255262" ) ,
6=> array( 0=>  "0xE20092012053100000002850D14E" ) ,
7=> array( 0=>  "0x300833B2DDD901400000000039BB" ) ,
8=> array( 0=>  "0xE2002996961802570960B3F06912" ) ,
9=> array( 0=>  "0x000000000000000000501420B8B6" ) ,
10=> array(0=>  "0x201203298478040001020252A5EC" ) ,
11=> array( 0=>  "0xE20010008007026819204FCAF906" ) ,
12=> array( 0=>  "0x0000000000000000000007485DF6" ) ,
13=> array( 0=>  "0xE2001036990F008812908EA5481C" ) ,
14=> array( 0=>  "0x0019000000000000000043B94C3A" ) ,
15=> array( 0=>  "0x0000000000000000004004490529" ) ,
16=> array( 0=>  "0x0000000000000000000010066E18" ) ,
17=> array( 0=>  "Error 0100:   syntax error at ''" ),
18=> array( 0=>  "Error 0102:   Error performing query" ),
19=> array( 0=> NULL ) 
);


$array_2=array(
0=> array( 0=> "0x0019000000000000000043B94C3A" ),
1=> array( 0=> "0x0000000000000000004004490529" ) ,
2=> array( 0=> "0x0000000000000000000010066E18" ) ,
3=> array( 0=> "0xE2004465650F015224401B255262" ),
);


$arrayiter = new RecursiveArrayIterator($array_1);
$iteriter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($arrayiter);
foreach ($iteriter as $value) {
    $array_1[] = $value;
}
$arrayiter = new RecursiveArrayIterator($array_2);
$iteriter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($arrayiter);
foreach ($iteriter as $value) {
$array_2[] = $value;
}

$results = array_diff($array_1, $array_2); 

echo'<pre>';
var_dump($results);
echo'</pre>';
```